# Why are consecutive timestamps in rosbag equal once in a while?

Tags: matlab, ros, gazebo-simu

I'm using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel version 5.15.0-53-generic) on a MSI GF66 and I have encountered a strange problem when analyzing a recorded rosbag.

I have to publish at 10 Hz by means of a Simulink model some messages to the `/cmd_vel` topic of a Turtlebot that moves in Gazebo and records the `/odom` and `/cmd_vel` topics. When analyzing the recorded bag, I notice something strange: every once in a while, two consecutive timestamps are exactly equal, even though the value of the two corresponding messages of the topic are not equal (it holds both for `/odom` and `/cmd_vel`).

I use the following script in Matlab to extract the information from the bag:

```
bagSelect = rosbag('BagPubSimulink.bag');

odomBag = select(bagSelect, 'Time', [bagSelect.StartTime bagSelect.EndTime], 'Topic', '/odom');

odomStructs = readMessages(odomBag, 'DataFormat','struct');

odomTime = odomBag.MessageList.Time;
```

Then, I cycle on `odomStructs` to extract the messages I need, let's say `odomX`.

Taking two instants `k` and `k + 1` when the problem occurs:

```
odomTime(k : k + 1) = {149.674000000000; 149.674000000000}

odomX(k : k + 1) = {-0.790906331505904; -0.787962666465643}`
```

I've noticed that this problem happens more frequently in the recorded bag when the considered topic has a high publishing frequency, e.g. if I record the `/clock` topic, this problem of consecutive timestamps being equal is magnified and can last for more than two consecutive timestamps.

Can you please help me with this problem?

In order to install ROS, I've followed the instructions at https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/ up to paragraph 1.1.5.

I've actually had to add some lines of code from the video linked in the same page, because they are not written there.

I'm sorry if something is not clear and whether I've not used the correct wording, but I'm new to both Ubuntu and ROS and I have a lot to learn.

Please, tell me if I have to provide some more details to work out a solution.

***Edit***

The problem is not due to the fact that the duplicated timestamps belong to two messages of the two topics I've recorded. In fact, this is `MessageList` of the variable `bagSelect`:

```
Time                Topic        MessageType            FileOffset

99.3160000000000    '/cmd_vel'  'geometry_msgs/Twist'   402403
99.3170000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     402497
99.3270000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     403261
99.3690000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     404025
99.4150000000000    '/cmd_vel'  'geometry_msgs/Twist'   404789
99.4170000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     404883
99.4610000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     405647
99.4610000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     406411
99.5050000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     407175
99.5160000000000    '/cmd_vel'  'geometry_msgs/Twist'   407939
99.5270000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     408033
99.5730000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     408797
99.6160000000000    '/cmd_vel'  'geometry_msgs/Twist'   409561
99.6170000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     409655
99.6650000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     410419
99.6650000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     411183
99.7120000000000    '/odom'     'nav_msgs/Odometry'     411947
99.7150000000000    '/cmd_vel'  'geometry_msgs/Twist'   412711
```

Interestingly, `/odom` is the only topic of this bag that suffers from this timestamps duplication problem. Thus, it seems that the problem doesn't affect topics that are published by myself.

As a matter of fact, I've tried recording the `/clock` topic only with the Turtlebot staying still in the Gazebo world, and inside the `MessageList` I get bunch of equal timestamps, referring to different time instants, meaning that the messages of `/clock` topic are correctly different the one from the other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem doing the following:

```matlab
for ii = 1 : length(odomStructs)
    sec = cast(odomStructs{ii}.Header.Stamp.Sec, 'double');
    nsec = cast(odomStructs{ii}.Header.Stamp.Nsec, 'double');
    odomTime(ii, 1) = sec + nsec*1e-9;
end
```

In this way, I read the `header.stamp`, which isn't affected by the same problem.

Don't mind the hypothetical inefficiency of the cycle: I implemented it this way just to make sure I was not taking the wrong element.

Comment: Doubles will roll over every 104 days or so if you try to use them for nanoseconds

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are reading in `odomTime` is not the time stamp of the message in the topic `/odom`, when you use `MessageList` the MessageList table contains one row for each message in the bag ( in your case a raw for `/odom` and a raw for `/cmd_vel` that's whey you are getting the time stamp twice.
please refer to [this tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ros/ug/work-with-rosbag-logfiles.html) for more info

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. In fact, if I look at `MessageList` of `bagSelect` (thus, previous to the extraction of the `odomBag`), the duplicated timestamps actually belong to the `/odom` topic. See the edit of my question for more info.

Comment: Can you please share the bag via a link here, I will try to debug it.

Comment: I've managed to solve my problem. I had to extract the header.stamp inside the bag associated the `/odom` topic. This issue still bothers me, because I wasn't experiencing it on the machine I was using previously (which was far less powerful), but at least I now can analyse a bag without making an interpolation of the time vector.
Thanks for your considerations.